# equivalent to mousemove for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mousemove

Was wondering if there were an equivalent for mousemove for mobile devices, such as touchmove or touchdrag or something.

I have an image within a container which can be panned on hover using mouse move. Is there a way I can optimise it for mobile devices too?

```
function MouseMove(e){
        var mouseCoordsX=(e.pageX - $imagePan.offset().left);
        var mouseCoordsY=(e.pageY - $imagePan.offset().top);
        var mousePercentX=mouseCoordsX/containerWidth;
        var mousePercentY=mouseCoordsY/containerHeight;
        var destX=-(((totalContentW-(containerWidth))-containerWidth)*(mousePercentX));
        var destY=-(((totalContentH-(containerHeight))-containerHeight)*(mousePercentY));
        var thePosA=mouseCoordsX-destX;
        var thePosB=destX-mouseCoordsX;
        var thePosC=mouseCoordsY-destY;
        var thePosD=destY-mouseCoordsY;
        var marginL=$imagePan_panning.css("marginLeft").replace("px", "");
        var marginT=$imagePan_panning.css("marginTop").replace("px", "");
        var animSpeed=500; //ease amount
        var easeType="easeOutCirc";
        if(mouseCoordsX>destX || mouseCoordsY>destY){
            //$imagePan_container.css("left",-thePosA-marginL); $imagePan_container.css("top",-thePosC-marginT); //without easing
            $imagePan_container.stop().animate({left: -thePosA-marginL, top: -thePosC-marginT}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
        } else if(mouseCoordsX<destX || mouseCoordsY<destY){
            //$imagePan_container.css("left",thePosB-marginL); $imagePan_container.css("top",thePosD-marginT); //without easing
            $imagePan_container.stop().animate({left: thePosB-marginL, top: thePosD-marginT}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
        } else {
            $imagePan_container.stop();
        }
    }

    $imagePan_panning.css("margin-left",($imagePan.width()-$imagePan_panning.width())/2).css("margin-top",($imagePan.height()-$imagePan_panning.height())/2);

    $imagePan.bind("mousemove", function(event){
        MouseMove(event);


    });
```

Answer (score 17):

Yep, you guessed it right, too.

It's `touchmove`. [Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchmove)